# Why does Google Testing Tool use the "id" attribute to generate a URL for the Microdata item?

Tags: schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets, structured-data

I'm using some Microdata to describe a blog post, and I'm surprised by the value return for Schema.org’s `BlogPosting` by the Google Developers Testing Tool.

I would have expected it to be the itemprop `url`, not a merge of the website URL and the item `id`.
Am I doing something wrong, or is it only a Google display issue?

```html
<div itemscope="itemscope"
     itemprop="blogPost"
     itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting"
     id="foobar">
  <a itemprop="url" href="/realone">real</a>
</div>
```

Value returned by https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/:

```
  BlogPosting:    http://www.example.com/foobar
  url:            http://www.example.com/realone
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is strange.

It’s definitely not conforming to the [Microdata Note](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/). Apart from Microdata’s `itemref` attribute, HTML5’s `id` attribute has no special meaning in Microdata.

If Google wants to use the `id` value anyway, they should at least generate the URL with a fragment identifier, i.e., `http://www.example.com/#foobar`.

My guess is that they are (probably unintentionally) handling HTML5’s `id` attribute the same way as Microdata’s `itemid` attribute. If using `itemid` instead of `id` in your example, Google’s Testing Tool output is the same, but this time correct.

Comment: Thanks. I made a too short example. Now that the id problem is "fixed". Do you know if it is possible to use something else than the url of the file being served  to create the blogposting value. I don't want the `http://www.example.com/` as the base url, well at least I need another path (for example `/log/` instead of `/`)

Comment: @user3074069: Not sure I understand exactly what you want to achieve. Maybe you want to create a separate question for this (and link it here), where you can give more details?