# Schema.org Rich Snippets offers [Offer] loading ID?

Tags: schema.org, microdata, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets

I've had structured markup set up on a website now for around a week and Google has indexed about 20% of it however it's still not displaying. After checking the markup was correct in the validating tool I noticed this:

[image: Product: All good]

Everything looks fine other than the

```
offers [Offer]: http://www.website.co.uk/price-excluding-tax-990
```

Now take a look at the source code:

```html
<div class="product-view" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <span itemprop="sku">PM90-0100</span>
    <div class="product-name">
      <h1 itemprop="name">Basket PM90-0100</h1>
    </div>
    <p class="availability in-stock">Availability: <span>In stock</span></p>
    <div class="price-box">
      <span class="price-excluding-tax">
        <span class="label">Excl VAT: </span>
        <span itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-990">
        <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock"/>
        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="GBP" />
        <span itemprop="price">£30.00</span>
      </span>
      <div itemprop="description" class="std">This is a brand new basket to fit various Freerider mobility scooters.</div>
      [code continues...]
```

Does this all look symantically correct? Somehow in Webmaster Tools it is grabbing the `price-excluding-tax-990` ID and using it in the `offers [Offer]:` - which seems odd.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Google Testing Tool use the "id" attribute to generate a URL for the Microdata item?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29491507/why-does-google-testing-tool-use-the-id-attribute-to-generate-a-url-for-the-mi)