# No Rich Snippet for AggregateOffer because my @id results in a 404?

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets

Pricerunner have their prices in SERP, so I wanted to do this as well. But for some reason, I don't get any prices in my results.

When I test with Google's structured data tool, I get:

[image: Structured data on Pricerunner]

But on my page I get:

[image: My page's structured data]

Apparently, the only difference (besides review), is the `@id`s.

If I follow Pricerunners ID then it's an actice link, but if I follow mine IDs, they result in a 404. Problem is, that I haven't set up any IDs?

If you take the first ID on my page, it's: `/lelo-lyla-2/product-2348`

ID is set to `product-2348`, wich is standard WooCommerce, but it's being added to the URL, so the URL is `/lelo-lyla-2/product-2348` witch results in a 404.

Same with the last ID in aggregated offer: `/lelo-lyla-2/price-list`

Where does `/price-list` come from? The `div`? Should I remove the `id="price-list"` from the `div`, in order to make it work, or?

```html
<div id="price-list" itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateOffer" itemscope itemprop="offers">
  <meta content="675" itemprop="lowPrice">
  <meta content="1039" itemprop="highPrice">
  <meta content="7" itemprop="offerCount">
  <meta content="DKK" itemprop="priceCurrency">
</div>
```

When I run the page through Google's test tool, it gets 0 errors. But I suspect it's because of the "invalid" IDs, or?

Comment: Note that you’ve used wrong quotation marks in your HTML example (I fixed it).

Answer (score 0):

[I think it’s a bug in Google’s SDTT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29492058/1591669) that it takes the value of the `id` attribute and uses it as identifier for the item. That’s the job of the `itemid` attribute in Microdata. I would suggest to ignore the extracted `@id`s that result from this; only care about those coming from `itemid`.

For Google’s [Product rich result (with aggregate offer)](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/products#aggregate_offer_properties) it doesn’t state that an identifier would be required to begin with. So the problem that you don’t get the rich result has most likely nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

As per Google's [Product-specific usage guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/products#guidelines), "Adult-related products are not supported."