# Schema.org WebPage markup on 'body' element with 'id' attribute

Tags: html, uri, schema.org, microdata

I would like to insert `WebPage` markup in my code. So it's written that this - `itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage"` - should be put into `body` tag. But in `body` tag I have `id="top-page"`.

When I copy the Microdata line to the `body` and test it with Google’s tool, it shows me `http://xxxx.yy/top-page` as @id.

How to avoid it?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you mean saying _"shows me `http://xxxx.yy/top-page`"_? Where does it show, and what you expect?

Comment: Thank You for You message. So one again I am trying to insert WebPage markup in my code. On https://schema.org/WebPage it's written that to do it the body tag should look like this <body itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">  but my body tag has id="top-page" and when I make <body id="top-page" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">, load it to the server and after that test my page with the markup tool from google webmaster tools, the tool shows me @id http://xxxx.yy/page-top which is wrong. And I think the tool should show - http://xxxx.yy - without page-top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [most likely a bug in Google’s tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29492058/1591669). You don’t have to worry about it. But if you do, there are two workarounds:

- Specify `itemid` on `body` in addition. This is the correct attribute responsible for providing an ID in Microdata, not `id`. You should provide the canonical URL of the web page as value.
- Specify `itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage"` on a different element (one that doesn’t have an `id` attribute). While it’s often useful to specify `WebPage` on the `body`, this is not required.

The first solution is preferable, as it’s generally a good practice to provide IDs for your structured data items.